# node js variable value outside function within same file

Tags: node.js, variables, asynchronous, export, require

I have the following piece of code

```
function getPNOP(callback){
  var result = result;
  connection.query('SELECT DISTINCT pnop FROM MASTER1', [], function(err, result){
    if(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
    callback({result: result[0].pnop});
  });
}
var PNOP;

getPNOP(function(resultsObject){
    var PNOP = resultsObject.result;
    exports.PNOP = PNOP;
    console.log(resultsObject.result)
})

console.log("Line 233 - PNOP updated : "+PNOP +CurrTime);
```

I am able to get the value of PNOP in the "console.log(resultsObject.result)" line but in the next console log line it is coming as undefined.

To see how to use the exported value outside the function I tried adding the following lines below the above code:

```
var myModule = require.('getPNOP');
var PNOP = myModule.PNOP;
```

but that does not work ...

Any suggestions on what I should be doing to get the PNOP variable value outside the getPNOP function?

Comment: Wanted to clarify that the entire code above is inside another function - where CurrTime variable is defined and in the log entry the CurrTime is correctly appearing - only the PNOP variable value is not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is synchronous, and it will run your code in such manner.

Your code will execute in the following order

1. Declare `PNOP` variable. Its `undefined` at this stage.
2. Call the function `getPNOP()`.
3. Run the `console.log(...)`. `PNOP` is still `undefined`.
4. Your anonymous callback function runs and declares a new variable `PNOP` and assigns it the value of `resultsObject.result`.

Either move your code that logs the `PNOP` value into your callback function, or wrap it in a promise that helps you run your asynchronous code run as if it was synchronous, as below.

```
function getPNOP(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        var result = result;
        connection.query('SELECT DISTINCT pnop FROM MASTER1', [], function(err, result){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }
            resolve(result[0].pnop);
        });
    });
}

getPNOP().then(function(PNOP){
    console.log("Line 233 - PNOP updated : "+PNOP +CurrTime);
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("An error occured");
});
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Will try this out.  However, not sure whether this will still make the PNOP variable value available outside this function - which is my requirement - not just capturing the value in the log.  Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, you can just declare it before and in the outer closure instead of inside the promise scope, and just assign it when you have the value. Though, in your original code you declare `PNOP` twice. Declare it in the scope you want to use it, and assign it when you have the value.

Comment: You should consider marking this as the answer if it works for you.

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply.  have not been able to get promise to work on my test machine - am trying to debug that.